# reading application usage information

Tags: android

As you probably know, when dialing `* # * # 4 6 3 6 # * # *` a testing menu appears.

On this menu you select > application statistics in order to read application usage time and lunch count.

I want to build a smart launcher that use this information.

Can anyone point me to a source code that implement reading this information?

Comment: +1 for the hidden testing menu :)

Comment: @OcuS: it's not testing menu, "4636" reads "INFO" on the phone keyboard.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Samsung Galaxy S7. Works on Nexus 5X. Is it a recent feature as the S7 is on the 7.0 when the N5X is on 7.1.2?

Answer (score 0):

The source for this menu can be found within the Settings application at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings

If you look in logcat, you will see tht entering that USSD code results in the firing of an intent:

> Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.settings/.TestingSettings }

Which is basically just a normal Activity launch, only for a non-launcher activity.  You can probably fire that intent from a program, or by having your program dial the ussd code.

Trying to grab the data to use in a program however will be difficult.  The settings application runs under the "system" uid, and is able to claim a lot of permissions not available to 3rd party apps.  Those involved in changing settings are almost entirely restricted, and even a fair amount of the read permissions probably are as well.

Looking through the source of the Settings app you will be able to see how it is doing things; looking at the AndroidManifest.xml will show you what permissions it is using - unfortunately, most of what you probably want to do likely requires ones from that list which you cannot obtain for your application.

Comment: Thanks!, so what I basically need to do is to build a service that logs lunch of application to gather this myself? can anyone recommend and a source code example that implement this?

Comment: @VadimKotov if you are going to insist on editing the old, obsolete answers despite my clear request that you not do so, please *at least* keep the original formatting.  I'm very specifically showing the link destination in the body so that people know where they are going - in many ways, understanding where code fits in the android source hierarchy is the most useful part of the links, regardless if they are working or dead.  Again, I'd prefer you didn't needless churn these on the main page by modifying them, but at least preserve the original intent with the source hierarchy visible.

Comment: @ChrisStratton ok, will do that